# non-secure (http) ampHtml links on a secure (https) page?

Tags: amp-html

Can we provide a non-secure (http) href as ampHtml rel link on a page served on https?
For example can a page `https://example.com/somecategory/somepage` have a `<link rel="ampHtml" href="http://amp.example.com/somecategory/somepage">` in it's header?

I know there won't be a mixed-content issue since the ampHtml rel links are not fetched by the browser. But could there be other implications like google not showing the amp page in the search etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPS is not a requirement for AMP.

For example, the Google AMP Cache has an [Example requesting image using plain HTTP](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview#example-requesting-image-using-plain-http).

HTTPS has other advantages, however: it allows you to use HTTP/2 if your server supports it, which [has significant speed advantages](https://www.httpvshttps.com/) and [Google uses HTTPS as a ranking signal](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html).

It also seems unusual you'd have a valid SSL/TLS certificate on `example.com` and not on `amp.example.com` - I suspect you can either (1) get a certificate that covers both `amp.example.com` and `example.com` or (2) serve your AMP pages from `example.com`. This is not AMP-related per se, but will let you use the aforementioned advantages of HTTPS.